Вытащить часть текста из строки в Google Sheets
В Google Sheets у меня есть следующий текст, хранимый в строчке:

{"af_order_type":"pickup","af_customer_user_id":"0cb8aebe-b067-4ff1-b0f8-5d4b2afda1cf","af_order_id":"74090155158",}

Мне нужно вытащить 74090155158 (он представлен текстом, как и вся строка).
Испробованные формулы (везде синтаксическая ошибка, разделитель должен быть ; ):
=IFERROR(MID(E2; SEARCH("af_order_id\":\""; E2) + LEN("af_order_id\":\""); SEARCH("\""; E2; SEARCH("af_order_id\":\""; E2) + LEN("af_order_id\":\"")) - (SEARCH("af_order_id\":\""; E2) + LEN("af_order_id\":\""))); "Не найдено")")))

=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(E2; "af_order_id\":\"([^\"]+)"); "Не найдено")


Регулярное выражение может быть такое af_order_id\D+(\d+) - ищем af_order_id, следом несколько не-цифр \D+, далее несколько цифр \d+, которые и захватываем ()
=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"af_order_id\D+(\d+)"); "Не найдено")


Вы гений! Низкий поклон!

@stwars7 Если ответ помог вам, отметьте его "решением", если поднял настроение добавьте голос "за". Спасибо.

=MID(A2;SEARCH("order_id";A2)+11;11)



везде синтаксическая ошибка, разделитель должен быть ;

Неправильно кавычки экранируешь. Надо не \", а "":
=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(E2;"""af_order_id"":""([^""]+)"); "Не найдено")

